# Saving form values in Web SQL database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, web-sql

I'm having trouble with saving form values into webSQL database. This is my first time using webSQL. The table is created, but I'm not able to save the form value into the table. All help appreciated!

Link to JSfiddle-- http://jsfiddle.net/earthtojayne/pp5VD/

html:

```
<div id="controls">
<p>Save drafts to the database</p>
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="Fname" /><br />
<label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="Lname" /><br />
 <label>Country: </label><input type="text" id="Country" /><br />
<button type="button" id="addDraft" onclick="addDraft();">Save as draft</button>
</div>
<div id="listholder">
<h3>Your saved drafts</h3>
<ul id="drafts">
</ul>
</div>
```

My Javascript:

```
if (window.openDatabase){
    //Create the database the parameters are 1. the database name 2.version number 3. a description 4. the size of the database (in bytes) 1024 x 1024 = 1MB
    var mydb = openDatabase("Testdb", "0.1", "Testing  Database", 1024 * 1024);

     //create the  table using SQL for the database using a transaction
     mydb.transaction(function(t){
         t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Fname VARCHAR(50), Lname VARCHAR(50), Country VARCHAR(100))");
});

}else{
alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}


//function to output to the database
function updateDrafts(transaction, results){
//initialise the listitems variable
var listitems = "";
//get the list holder ul
var listholder = document.getElementById("drafts");

//clear the list of drafts ul
listholder.innerHTML = "";

var i;
//Iterate through the results
 for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
    //Get the current row from database
    var row = results.rows.item(i);

    listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + row.Fname + " - " + row.Lname + " - " + row.Country + "(<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteDraft(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Draft</a>)";
}
}

//function to get the list from the database

function outputDrafts() {
//check to ensure the mydb object has been created
if (mydb) {
    //Get all the data from the database with a select statement, set outputCarList as the callback    function for the executeSql command
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM mydb", [], updateDrafts);
    });
} else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
}
}
//function to add to the database

function addDraft() {
//check to ensure the mydb object has been created
if (mydb) {
    //get the values of text inputs
    var Fname= document.getElementById("Fname").value;
    var Lname= document.getElementById("Lname").value;
    var Country = document.getElementById("Country").value;


    //Test to ensure that the fields are not empty
    if (Fname !== "" && Lname !== "" && Country !== "") {
        //Insert the user entered details into the  table, note the use of the ? placeholder, these    will replaced by the data passed in as an array as the second parameter
        mydb.transaction(function(t) {
            t.executeSql("INSERT INTO mydb (Fname, Lname, Country) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [Fname, Lname, Country]);
            outputDrafts();
        });
    } else {
        alert("You must enter your first name, last name and country!");
    }
} else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
}
}
//function to remove  from the database, passed the row id as it's only parameter

function deleteDraft(id) {
//check to ensure the mydb object has been created
if (mydb) {

    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("DELETE FROM mydb WHERE id=?", [id], outputDrafts);
    });
} else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
}
}

outputDrafts();
```

Comment: I get the following error in console.log: Uncaught ReferenceError: addDraft is not defined line 120.

Answer (score 0):

If you click JSHint at the top of your fiddle it says you have mixed tabs and spaces.
Red dots show where in the javascript this occurs.
Click the tidyUp link at the top and then click Run.
All is well then.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the 'addDraft' function call happened before it appears on DOM. The solution is to remove the onclick form `<button type="button" id="addDraft" onclick="addDraft();">Save as draft</button>` and write the vent the js file.
    the updated file are as:

```
//HTML
<div id="controls">
  <p>Save drafts to the database</p>
  <label>First Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Fname" />
  <br />
  <label>Last Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Lname" />
  <br />
  <label>Country: </label>
  <input type="text" id="Country" />
  <br />
  <button type="button" id="addcar">Save as draft</button>
</div>
<div id="listholder">
  <h3>Your saved drafts</h3>
  <ul id="drafts">
  </ul>
</div>


//Js
 var mydb = openDatabase("Testdb", "0.1", "Testing  Database", 1024 * 1024);
if (window.openDatabase) {
  //Create the database the parameters are 1. the database name 2.version number 3. a description 4. the size of the database (in bytes) 1024 x 1024 = 1MB


  //create the  table using SQL for the database using a transaction
  mydb.transaction(function(t) {
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Fname VARCHAR(50), Lname VARCHAR(50), Country VARCHAR(100))");
  });

} else {
  alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}


//function to output the list of cars in the database
function updateDrafts(transaction, results) {
  //initialise the listitems variable
  var listitems = "";
  //get the list holder ul
  var listholder = document.getElementById("drafts");

  //clear the list of drafts ul
  listholder.innerHTML = "";

  var i;
  //Iterate through the results
  for (i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
    //Get the current row from database
    var row = results.rows.item(i);

    listholder.innerHTML += "<li>" + row.Fname + " - " + row.Lname + " - " + row.Country + "(<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='deleteDraft(" + row.id + ");'>Delete Draft</a>)";
  }
}

//function to get the list of cars from the database

function outputDrafts() {
  //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
  if (mydb) {
    //Get all the cars from the database with a select statement, set outputCarList as the callback function for the executeSql command
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
      t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM mydb", [], updateDrafts);
    });
  } else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
  }
}
//function to add the car to the database

function addDraft() {
  //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
  if (mydb) {
    //get the values of the make and model text inputs
    var Fname = document.getElementById("Fname").value;
    var Lname = document.getElementById("Lname").value;
    var Country = document.getElementById("Country").value;


    //Test to ensure that the user has entered both a make and model
    if (Fname !== "" && Lname !== "" && Country !== "") {
      //Insert the user entered details into the cars table, note the use of the ? placeholder, these will replaced by the data passed in as an array as the second parameter
      mydb.transaction(function(t) {
        t.executeSql("INSERT INTO mydb (Fname, Lname, Country) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [Fname, Lname, Country]);
        outputDrafts();
      });
    } else {
      alert("You must enter a make and model!");
    }
  } else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
  }
}
//function to remove a car from the database, passed the row id as it's only parameter

function deleteDraft(id) {
  //check to ensure the mydb object has been created
  if (mydb) {
    //Get all the cars from the database with a select statement, set outputCarList as the callback function for the executeSql command
    mydb.transaction(function(t) {
      t.executeSql("DELETE FROM mydb WHERE id=?", [id], outputDrafts);
    });
  } else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
  }
}

outputDrafts();
var link = document.getElementById("addcar");

link.onclick = function () { alert(1) 
addDraft();
};
```